# Adding a class in a another div based on another class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove a div class  when another div has the class 'scroll-to-fixed-fixed' using jQuery. The scroll function works fine and the sticky header appears as desired. but its the condition that doesn't seem to work. I have tried the following code but no luck. Kindly assist:
:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 10) {
    //clearHeader, not clearheader - caps H
    $(".scroll-nav-holder").addClass("scroll-to-fixed-fixed");
  } else {
    $(".scroll-nav-holder").removeClass("scroll-to-fixed-fixed");
  }
});

if ($('.scroll-nav-holder').hasClass('scroll-to-fixed-fixed')) {
  $(".logo-holder").removeClass('nodisplay');
} else {
  $(".logo-holder").addClass('nodisplay');
}
```

```css
.logo-holder {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.nodisplay {
  display: none;
}

.scroll-nav-holder {
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
}

.container {
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

.scroll-to-fixed-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo-holder nodisplay">something here</div>

<div class="container">
  More stuff
</div>
<div class="container">
  More stuff
</div>
<div class="container">
  More stuff
</div>
<div class="container">
  More stuff
</div>
<div class="container">
  More stuff
</div>


<div class="scroll-nav-holder">
  somethin more here
</div>
```

Comment: why are you not just doing it in the if? You already know if it is being added or removed so why are you checking?

Comment: Agreed ^. Would just move `$(".logo-holder").removeClass('nodisplay');` into the `if(y >10)` bit. Also the code snippet feature here seems to work as expected. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: One more tip: try to use [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className-state) function. It would do you code much more readable and clean from my point of view.

Comment: Could it be added outside the scroll function since on my website i do not control over the scroll function?

Comment: One caveat to the `toggleClass` function, it can get out of sync with your rules though. I agree with dganenco that it makes code more readable, but I personally would leave it as explicit show/hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above you should include you `.logo-header` condition inside `scroll` event. Also, I slightly refactored your code using [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function to make it a bit cleaner:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // ?
 const toggleCondition = $(this).scrollTop() > 10;
 $(".scroll-nav-holder").toggleClass('scroll-to-fixed-fixed', toggleCondition);
 $(".logo-holder").toggleClass('nodisplay', toggleCondition);
});
```

```css
.logo-holder {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.nodisplay {
  display: none;
}

.scroll-nav-holder {
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
}

.container {
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

.scroll-to-fixed-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo-holder nodisplay">something here</div>

<div class="container">
  More stuff
</div>
<div class="container">
  More stuff
</div>
<div class="container">
  More stuff
</div>
<div class="container">
  More stuff
</div>
<div class="container">
  More stuff
</div>


<div class="scroll-nav-holder">
  somethin more here
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Would there be a way to include it outside the scroll event?

Comment: I would say no. Do you have such requirement?

Comment: Yes.  May be another way to look as it is .Basically when scroll-nav-holder would reach the top of the window removeClass 'nodisplay' from .logo-holder?

Comment: You can simply add `scroll` event handler and do whatever you need there. Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dganenco/qngdbmts/)

Answer (score 0):

Just put it inside the if else statements where your also change the class of the "scroll-nav-holder" like so:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 10) {
    //clearHeader, not clearheader - caps H
    $(".scroll-nav-holder").addClass("scroll-to-fixed-fixed");
    $(".logo-holder").removeClass('nodisplay');
  } else {
    $(".scroll-nav-holder").removeClass("scroll-to-fixed-fixed");
    $(".logo-holder").addClass('nodisplay');
  }
});
```